# Trouble defining an IList<T> where T is an generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I am attempting to declare and use an interface like this:

```
public interface IItem<T>
{
  string Name { get; set; }
  T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine until I attempt to create a list of these items.  This fails to compile:

```
public interface IThing
{
    string Name { get; }
    IList<IItem<T>> ThingItems { get; }
}
```

so I am not certain where the issue is.  The items value is not defined until runtime, and I need to have collections of the items.  I figure that this is a fairly standard pattern, but I can not see where I am falling down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're falling down because the compiler wants to know what kind of items are in your list. So if you don't know yet, just create a non-generic base interface, and derive a generic more specific interface:

Maybe this helps you out:

```
public interface IItem
{
  string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IItem<T>: IItem
{
  T Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IThing
{
    string Name { get; }
    IList<IItem> Items { get; }
}

public interface IThing<T>: IThing
{
    string Name { get; }
    IList<IItem<T>> Items { get; }
}
```

Comment: in your example, you'd want IItem to have the value property still, just return object.

Comment: That depends if you're gonna need it. Maybe you would also want to expose the Type for the item (e.g. what typeof(T) returns), etc.
If there are non-generic methods on the interface (like, ProcessItem), you probably don't need the object value since they will be able to use the generic value in their implementation.

Comment: This comes as close as I think I can.  I just would never have the final interface you have here IThing<T> as the items vary indepenent of the things.

Comment: That's fine too, of course. I added it so that the pattern is clear with non-generic and generic interfaces in such situations.

Answer (score 6):

Your class needs to be generic too (`Thing<T>`) or else the list can't know what type to use.

```
public interface Thing<T>
{
    string Name { get; }
    IList<IItem<T>> thingItems { get; }
}
```

**EDIT**
It compiles now.

**EDIT**
It seems you want your `IItem<T>` to be in terms of any type.  This won't work in C#. You could create IList> here, but that is less than ideal, since you loose your typing when you want to get the items out.

Comment: Won't compile. You can't have fields in an interface.

Comment: But this will not work in the case shown.  The types of the items in thingItems vary based on the item, not the thing.

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to get what you want with generics. Generics allow you to create a collection of objects that are the SAME object. Otherwise you're stuck using a higher level class (Object being the most generic) and casting them through some method to get the actual stored object.

Comment: This is not a covariance/contravariance issue - it is just unknown what the concete type of Thing.thingItems will be at the point of creating a Thing instance.

Comment: Daniel: Ya know, I think you are right.  I had a solution in my head that wouldn't work because [co|contra]variance and I never put it down.  Thanks.  I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

- Interfaces cannot contain fields (data members)
- A type containing a generic type is also a generic type

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You can't declare fields in an `interface`. (rationale: a field is considered an implementation detail, which is the thing interfaces are designed to abstract away)
2. You can't have a generic field without specifying the type parameter (unless you have a type parameter on the declaring type too).

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instace of `Thing` you have to know what the type of `Thing.thingItems` is. So the following is the correct way.

```
public interface Thing<T>
{
    String Name { get; }
    IList<IItem<T>> thingItems { get; }
}
```

If you do not know the concret type at the point of instanciating `Thing` you can only use a common base class or a common interface for the type.

```
public interface Thing<T>
{
    String Name { get; }
    IList<IItem<ThingParameterBase>> thingItems { get; }
}
```

Or with a common interface.

```
public interface Thing<T>
{
    String Name { get; }
    IList<IItem<IThingParameter>> thingItems { get; }
}
```

Comment: I could make it IList<IItem<object>> ThingItems I guess.  I just feel that this smells to high heaven.

Comment: ...and it would give you covariance issues, since a IItem<object> is not compatible with IItem<AnyThingElse>!